# inserting data depending on a ROW

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I am trying to update a table on phpmyadmin. The status column should be updated depending on who's id statue's is being updated.

this is the first code in which it will check the statues. If the statues were updated, the button will be disabled. Otherwise, the buttons will be enabled:

```
<div class = "table-responsive">
<form action= "e.php" method="post">
<table class="table">

<thead>
  <tr class="active">
    <!--<td><input type="checkbox" id = "chckHead" /> Select</td>-->
    <td>Patient Name</td>
    <td>Patient ID</td>
    <td>Medicin</td>
    <td>DONE</td>
    <td>Male Side</td>


  </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>

  <?php 
 $sql="SELECT * from medicin_refill";   
 $result = mysqli_query($dbhandle,$sql);
 while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
     $id=$row['id'];
    Print ("<tr class='warning'>");
    //print("<td><input type='checkbox' class = 'chcktbl' id='ch' /></d>");
    print("<td>".$id."</td>");
    print("<td>".$row['pname']."</td>");
    print("<td>".$row['medicin']."</td>");
    if ($row['status']== "DONE" or $row['status']=="Male Side"){
        print("<td><button name='button1' id='button1' class='btn btn-secondry btn-sm btn-block' disabled>Updated</button></td>");
        print("<td><button name='button1' id='button1' class='btn btn-secondry btn-sm btn-block' disabled>Updated</button></td>");}


    else{
         print("<td><button name='button1' id='button1' class='btn btn-danger' >DONE</button></td>");
         print("<td><button name='button2' id='button2' class='btn btn-danger' >Male Side</button></td>");}
 }

    ?>
```

In the other code that I will put, the statues will be updated. But my problem is that all rows' data are being updated not only the specified row:

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM logph WHERE id = '$login_session1'";
          $result = mysqli_query($dbhandle,$sql);
$sql1="SELECT id from medicin_refill";
            $result1 = mysqli_query($dbhandle,$sql1);
            $id= $row['id'];


    if (isset($_POST['button1'])) {
        $result = mysqli_query($dbhandle,$query);
    mysqli_query($dbhandle,"UPDATE medicin_refill SET status='DONE' where id ='$id'") or die(mysqli_error($dbhandle));}

    else if (isset($_POST['button2'])) {
        $result = mysqli_query($dbhandle,$query);
    mysqli_query($dbhandle,"UPDATE medicin_refill SET status='Male Side'") or die(mysqli_error($dbhandle));}

    header("Location:employee page loged.php");
```

My question is how do I update a specific row's statue without updating the whole rows' statues? 
Thank You in advance!

Comment: i dont actually see a question/

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: i dont see a form, how are you processing the button trigger? its the id that you need to pass to make the query `UPDATE medicin_refill SET status='DONE' WHERE id=XXX`

Comment: the first form will send the data to the second code

Comment: there is no form in the code, cant read minds here.

Comment: sorry. Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this before your edited the question, i dont think the id from

`SELECT id FROM logph WHERE id = '$login_session1'`

is the id you want so ..in the  first while block we need the id, to be past in the form submission. There are a couple of ways but lets add it as a value to the button

for each button add

```
value='".$id."'
```

then $id will be `$_POST['id']` in e.php which is the value to use in the update